# Chakra-UI: How to apply size to Heading using chakra factory function

Tags: chakra-ui

I want

```html
<SidebarHeading>heading</SidebarHeading>
```

to be a synonym for

```html
<Heading mt={5} size={'sm'}>heading</Heading>
```

I tried

```js
const SidebarHeading chakra(Heading, { baseStyle: { mt: 5, size: 'sm' } })
```

This applies the top margin but not the size. How do I specify the size?

Is the second parameter of `chakra()` documented somewhere? I've only found a [set of usage examples](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/features/chakra-factory).